# ¿Se puede hacer un test con JUNIT a un método privado

Tags: java, junit, test

Estoy trabajando en unos test de una aplicación y cuando intento hacerle un test a un método privado me sale el siguiente mensaje sobre la linea de código que llama al método.

```
has private access
```

Me gustaría que alguien aportara alguna wiki sobre el tema si es posible, si no, con una aclaración es suficiente.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes replantearte tu pregunta como: ¿Se *debe* hacer un test con JUNIT a un método privado?

Cuando haces una prueba unitaria de una clase/objeto, lo que quieres comprobar es que todas y cada una de las funcionalidades implementadas funcionan correctamente en (idealmente) todos los posibles escenarios. Dichas funcionalidades serán usadas por otro código, el código cliente.

Ese código cliente tiene que poder acceder a tus métodos, con lo que lo normal es que estos sean públicos. Estos métodos públicos pueden delegar parte de la funcionalidad en métodos privados para hacer el código más modular, legible, mantenible... pero puedes considerarlos como "pertenecientes" al método público que los llama.

Por tanto, lo que realmente necesitas probar, exclusivamente, son los métodos expuestos.

Dicho de otro modo: Los métodos privados son los detalles de implementación que deben estar ocultos a los usuarios, testear estos métodos rompe la idea de encapsulamiento.

Puedes encontrar más información en preguntas similares hechas en [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105007/should-i-test-private-methods-or-only-public-ones) y en el site de [StackExchange de Ingeniería del Software (también en inglés)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135047/new-to-tdd-should-i-avoid-private-methods-now).